# Why is my code getting the width of the screen and not the parent?

Tags: html, css

So, example.. When I hover over my button I want a line to scale from the middle to the edges of the button. But its getting the width of the screen and scaling it to that. Here's an example on JSFiddle, hope this helps!

https://jsfiddle.net/RVKuzmik/kabnL1yw/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="connectbtn">
            test
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>


#connectbtn {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}

#connectbtn:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1%;
    background-color: tomato;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#connectbtn:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: Seems you don't understand display: block; (which h1 has by default). Block elements grab as much horizontal space as availlable. Adding `h1 { background-color: #eee; }` will help you understand this. If you want to limit the h1' width to it's content, add `display: inline-block;`. You will also have to add `position: relative;` for the `:before`absolute position to relate to the h1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `#connectbtn:before` a `left: 0; position`.

```
#connectbtn:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1%;
    background-color: tomato;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: This does actually help but it only solves one problem. The other problem is that the line still moves throughout the whole 100% of the screen instead of 100% of the h1 tag. Thank you though!

Comment: Seems you don't understand `display: block;` (which h1 has by default). Block elements grab as much horizontal space as availlable.

Comment: In addition, setting the h1 display type to `inline-block` will change the width to match the width of the text. If you want to center the h1 tag, the parent (body in this case) will need a `text-align: center;` property.

Answer (score 0):

Add following styles to #connectbtn

```
position: relative;
max-width: 50px;
```

Comment: The relative style doesn't fit my style of webpage. And i've been walking away from using px in my webpages.

Comment: *The relative style doesn't fit my style of webpage* LOL - that's how absolute positioning of child elements **must** be done.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is in your absolute-positioning with pseudo-elements. Without specifying an offset, the `:before` gets positioned relative to the element (like with `position: relative`). You need to specify that the pseudo-element should be **moved** rather than offset.

To resolve this, you simply need to add `left: 0` to `#connectbtn:before`:

```css
#connectbtn {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

#connectbtn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  background-color: tomato;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#connectbtn:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="connectbtn">
    test
  </h1>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: `#connectbtn:before` is an inline element, that's why it is start at the same position then text, you need to convert it to a block element.

```css
html, body, h1 {
    margin, 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#connectbtn {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

#connectbtn:before {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: tomato;
   visibility: hidden;
   transform: scaleX(0);
   transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#connectbtn:hover:before {
   visibility: visible;
   transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="connectbtn">
    test
</h1>
```